# Reduce the opacity of a background image in parent div without affecting child elements? (Twitter Bootsrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been using Twitter Bootstrap to polish up the look of a website. A sample of my html code is:

```
<div class = 'container-fluid bg-1'>
            <div id ='yield_wrap'>
                <div id = 'field-wrap' style = 'height:40px;'>
                    <div class='form-groups'>
                        <input autocomplete='off' autofocus class='form-control' name='yield' placeholder='yield' type='text'/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As can be seen, the parent div here is 'container-fluid bg-1', whereby bg-1 relates to the background image as optimised by the following CSS:

```
.bg-1{  
    background: url("https://loonylabs.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/peptides.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity:0.9; 
}
```

However, when setting the opacity of this image, it also seems to affect all child elements within the container div - this is not what I want. I have looked extensively for a way to stop this from happening (it seems to be a fairly common problem) however, I couldn't find anything that really works in my case. I have a feeling it may be possible to use a pseudo div, but I am unsure how to get this to work. I know this seems like a fairly trivial issue, but any suggestions/tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use pseudo element for this:

```
.bg-1 {
  position: relative;
}
.bg-1:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  background: url("https://loonylabs.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/peptides.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/gMgBYY)